# AWS DynamoDB: What does the graph implies? What needs to be done? Few of my btachwrite (delete request) failed

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cloudwatch, throttling

Can somebody tell what needs to be done?
Im facing few issues when I am having 1000+ events.
Few of them are not getting deleted after my process.
Im doing a batch delete through batchwriteitem

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Each partition on a DynamoDB table is subject to a hard limit of 1,000 write capacity units and 3,000 read capacity units. If your workload is unevenly distributed across partitions, or if the workload relies on short periods of time with high usage (a burst of read or write activity), the table might be throttled.
It seems You are using DynamoDB adaptive capacity, however, DynamoDB adaptive capacity automatically boosts throughput capacity to high-traffic partitions. However, each partition is still subject to the hard limit. This means that adaptive capacity can't solve larger issues with your table or partition design. To avoid hot partitions and throttling, optimize your table and partition structure.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/dynamodb-table-throttled/

One way to better distribute writes across a partition key space in Amazon DynamoDB is to expand the space. You can do this in several different ways. You can add a random number to the partition key values to distribute the items among partitions. Or you can use a number that is calculated based on something that you're querying on.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-partition-key-sharding.html